# In Eclipse what can I use to encapsulate a block of code that I can toggle to view or not?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In Visual Studio I remember using some sort of syntax to encapsulate code and be able to toggle it open and close to view.

Is there something similar in Eclipse? (JAVA)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java equivalent to #region in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344524/java-equivalent-to-region-in-c).

Comment: @Soner: No need to be a perfectionist. :-) I think anything over 50% (or even 40%) is good enough.

Comment: @Soner... No need for sarcasm... I did increase it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java doesn't have regions, unlike C#. So there is no user-defined means to define regions that you can collapse.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean [code fold](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Folding-in-Eclipse-Text-Editors/folding.html) ?

[image]

Comment: @Hristo :) :) unfortunately on win machine now

Comment: @Jigar... eh, its not so unfortunate if its Windows 7

Comment: There is a request to allow custom regions in code folding in eclipse, but it is still open: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=63808