# how to make section break in eclipse like visual studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to make code section wise like so in left side i can expand or collapse our code

Like when we write function it is expanded or collapse but can we make our custom section

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344524/java-equivalent-to-region-in-c-sharp

Comment: I have searched out in stackoverflow but i did not get but Thanks for your reply Matt Wolfe :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spring source tool suite this is enable by using

option Preferences --> Java -->Editor -->Folding .And check the Enable folding option.

Check whether this option is present in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i want to create my own section like this section is used for "something" and that section i can fold or expand like that