# #pragma mark equivalent in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

The [jump bar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-organizing-and-editing-source-files) in Xcode and [#pragma mark](https://nshipster.com/pragma/) in Objective-C are very helpful and I'm looking for anything similar in Android Studio (either native or by plug-in).

Comment: Check out the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18740965/1758547

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java equivalent to #region in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344524/java-equivalent-to-region-in-c-sharp)

Comment: you can check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47565502/5381331

Comment: Since you didn't specify the language, it's also worth mentioning that Android Studio does support `#pragma mark` in C++ code.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

In Android Studio you can add regions using the steps below

> 1. Open the IDE you are using
> 2. Select the code you want to group
> 3. Press Ctrl + Alt + T (Cmd + Opt + T for mac) and select the “region .. end region comments”
> 4. Now the code is surrounded with “//region” / “//endregion” lines, you can see that the region can be fold-able
> 5. You can now edit the description of your group
> 6. You can easily see the code within your group without having to expand the group, just hover the group description with the mouse pointer

See [this](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2014/06/21/android-studio-intellij-idea-code-regions/)

Comment: Cool, I wish it showed in the Structure view (CMD + 7) in bold like it did in the Xcode dropdown but there's always going to be development tool differences.

Comment: where can we suggest for what @StuartP's talking about? I mean a way to add it in Structure View.

Comment: Since Android Studio is based on Intellij IDEA, and since this feature is coming to IDEA, hopefully we just have to wait for a future release of Android Studio to see regions in the structure view! Here's the YouTrack issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-129599

Comment: In Android Studio 3 it (regions) do show in the structure view - which is great, though I'm finding it a bit buggy.

Comment: Is it possible to have the structure view show the region expanded by default? Looks like it always collapses the signatures on startup.

Comment: @StuartP. it shows in Cmd+F12 (structure view popup) for me, times have changed it seems :-)

Answer (score 19):

Meet [**custom folding regions**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-folding-settings.html), the IntelliJ IDEA (where Android Studio is derived from) way to customized code structure support (that is what jump bar serves in Xcode).

Keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌥⌘T</kbd> or manual typing,

```kotlin
// region REGION_NAME
// YOUR CODE HERE
// endregion
```

Here is the missing gif demo (that people want in their official doc) showing how Android Studio behaves when two customized regions are added.

[image: demo]

###### Official Documentation

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-folding-settings.html

Comment: Note that the line above a new region or region end cannot contain // as it will then not be recognized. Also, whenever you change any region, the structure box will collapse all current regions. Not very "intelli".

Answer (score 8):

No idea why answers by Android Developers mostly lacking clarity. Here is my contribution.

Simply said, just wrap the codes with

```
//region SECTION NAME
...
//endregion
```

[image]