# Folding error using //region in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, folding

After creating a region in Android Studio, located under the end tag of another region, the code folds upward to the end tag of the previous region instead of folding downward through hundreds of lines of code to my //endregion tag for the new region.

I looked at the settings in Android Studio for Cold Folding. But it seems nothing there helps.

What am I missing? Folding is useless if it can't fold hundreds or thousands of lines.

[image: Example of folding problem]

Comment: you can give link to your picture

Comment: http://lh4.ggpht.com/djEOC2sKXGnQqqPbgQAJSHYrTqohmM-LLraup7dDKE6cRu9XFgd4JeOk6GOWKDeFfpB2zjxUVh2ojR4nOv3IislQ

Answer (score 8):

**Update as on 13-Sep-2015:** I believe that this issue is fixed now. I am successfully able to do `//region` in all my files
[Here is the actual answer](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2014/06/21/android-studio-intellij-idea-code-regions/)

Answer (score 1):

My answer:
Instead of folding using the arrows on the left just I just used "ctrl" + "-"
Or used "ctrl" + "shift" + "-" to fold all.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a buggy feature of the Android Studio IDE. There are some various work-arounds [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344524/java-equivalent-to-region-in-c-sharp/18740965#18740965).

There's a defect filed for this on [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=157318&q=region&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars), which, is marked as 'closed' for Android Studio 2.2.