# How to organise the java files in the editor? Is there anyway like having regions in C#

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, organization, code-organization

I wanted to organise my class written in java. Currently i am using intellij and eclipse. Lot of fields variables and methods are there in my class. It looks lenghty. Is there any way to organise it.

Comment: Are you sure your class *needs* all those fields and methods? Perhaps you should break it into multiple classes? When a class gets unwieldy to work with, that's *often* (but not always) a sign that it's doing too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Netbeans you can use:

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {
}
// </editor-fold>
```

In InteliJ:

```
//region GeneratedCode                         
private void initComponents() {
}
//endregion
```

And for eclipse check here:
http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/editor/ref-preferences-folding.htm

Answer (score 0):

There's no such equivalent to Java like C#. Some IDEs - Intellij, for instance, or Eclipse - can fold depending on the code types involved (constructors, imports etc.), but there's nothing quite like #region in Java

You can read up on more on
[Java equivalent to #region in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344524/java-equivalent-to-region-in-c-sharp)