# Android studio bad folding

Tags: android-studio, folding

Ok, I have some fictional class

```
public class TEMP {
    String data;
    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (data != null) {

            }
        }
    };
}
```

And it looks like this in Android Studio:
[image]

If I collapse all - it looks ugly:
[image]

If I remove that `if` block inside `onClick()` - it looks good:
[image]

Why is this happening and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: I have seen the same issue and it is annoying to me as well. I think we should either file a bug to Android Studio/Intellij IDEA , or to find the bug that most probably somebody else has already created.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, so I'm not sure how helpful this is.

This is folding the function into a lambda-like visual structure with Java 8 lambda-notation. Single method interfaces are (almost) equivalent to lambdas in Java 8. Android Studio currently does NOT support Java 8 lambda notation (details found at the bottom of this answer: [Is it possible to use Java 8 for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development)).

A workaround IS available for Java 8, based on the Jack toolchain. Here is the [the workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36880115/how-to-enable-jack-java-android-compiler-kit-in-android-studio), and here is the [deprecation](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html) of the Jack toolchain.

Another note is that according to [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html#supported_features) and [here](https://medium.com/@1priyank1/use-java-8-language-features-android-studio-f3e3d1011fe3), Android Studio 2.4 preview 4 and later appears to support actual lambda notation. Note that these are previews, and the latest official version is 2.3.2.

As for how to fix it, I don't believe it is possible. You may be able to use the [region feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344524/java-equivalent-to-region-in-c-sharp/18740965#18740965) to duplicate what you are trying to achieve. The link above is a how-to sort of thing.

Comment: Hm, I forgot about this issue already;). Seems like in some later releases guys fixed that. In current version (2.3.2) I cannot reproduce that.

Comment: I'm still seeing the issue though. I have some rather large anonymous classes within my project that fold into a lambda expression instead of folding all the way in. I'm running 2.3.2 as well.