# Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, jack-compiler

When I tried to update my android project to use Java 8 after getting android studio 2.1 and android N SDK
by adding

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

I had this error

> Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.

What should I do?

Comment: show build.gradle file

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36880115/how-to-enable-jack-java-android-compiler-kit-in-android-studio/36903323#36903323

Answer (score 323, accepted):

> Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either
>   enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.

The error say that you have to **enable Jack**.

To enable support for Java 8 in your Android project, you need to configure your `build.gradle` file like that

```
android {
  ...


  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "24rc2"
  defaultConfig {
  ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

Comment: After adding the following line I get Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

Comment: @AdityaKamath post your problem in new question so I can help you.

Comment: Adding retroLambda solved that problem for me.

https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda

Comment: Does this work with annotation processing, or would it break compilation?

Comment: Luckily we won't need this in a few weeks. Android will have full support for Java 8 language features. Jack will be deprecated. More details here: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html

Comment: **Jack** is no longer required.  See this: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Were you able to remove jackOptions and still get Java 8 to work?

Comment: @airowe At this point, Java 8 works without Jack.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky If I remove the jackOptions block from my Gradle, it still throws an error. Are you using retroLambda?

Comment: @airowe Not using any of the legacy plugins.  Read: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html

Comment: To avoid Jack just update your Gradle to 3.0.0-beta1
.
Built-in support for Java 8 libraries and certain Java 8 language features. Jack is no longer required, and you should first disable Jack to use the improved Java 8 support built into the default toolchain.
.
check this one
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0.html

Comment: Did anyone got this error :transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug after adding jack ?

Comment: @BiswasKhayargoli Yes i got that issue "transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug". Any fixes for it?