# Can I target an older Java environment than the compiler?

Tags: java, jar, build

I have built a jar file with the newest JRE.  When I try to use it in another computer, I get an error that says that the JRE is older.

Can I build a JAR file that will run on this older version of JRE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can newer JRE versions run Java programs compiled with older JDK versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895969/can-newer-jre-versions-run-java-programs-compiled-with-older-jdk-versions)

Comment: Other way around I think, @Pieter - can you compile with a new JDK to target an older JRE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can specify the target Java version at `javac`s command line:

`$ javac -help
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
...
 -source <release>          Provide source compatibility with specified release
 -target <release>          Generate class files for specific VM version`

This is also supported by build tools like [maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) and [gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41017544/how-to-specify-source-and-target-compatibility-in-java-module).

## But you have to be careful:

This does **not** check that you don't access classes or methods from the JRE which are not (yet) available in the old version...