# Android Studio enable Java8 support

Tags: android, gradle, java-8, android-gradle-plugin, jack

I need to enable Java8 support in my project. All the answers that I find are outdated and I can't figure out what actually has to be done. So far I have done this :

1. Added `compileOptions` :

```
android {
  compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

**This gives me the error below :**

```
ERROR: Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.


ERROR: Jack is required to support Java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.
```

2. I tried to enable jack using `jackOptions`. But the gradle could not identify `jackOptions`. I read somewhere that jack is deprecated. I have not idea where to go from here.

gradle version : 4.10.3

Comment: What version of Gradle and the plugin are you using?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004069/errorjack-is-required-to-support-java-8-language-features) didn't work?

Comment: Follow these instructions https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support jack is deprecated

Comment: Update to latest Android Studio and latest Gradle. Jack is deprecated and not required anymore

Comment: My gradle version is 4.10.3 and I am already running Android Studio 3.3.1

Comment: As I have mentioned, Android documentation tell us to simply do the Step -1 above. But that alone is giving me the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are building using commandline instead of android-studio.
export ANDROID_HOME=/android/SDK_26
export JAVA_HOME=/sw/licensed/sun/jdk/1.8.0_91
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
chmod 777 gradlew
./gradlew
./gradlew assembleDebug

SDK_26: This is SDK-26 toolchain downloaded using sdk-manager.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add to repositories google() and try

or

I am not sure but this can be help to you.

*Clean project -> delete .idea and .gradle files -> invalidate cache and restart -> build project*

Answer (score -3):

Try enable jackOptions, like here:

```
android {
....
defaultConfig {
 ...
  jackOptions {
    enabled true
  }
}

compileOptions {
  sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}
```

Comment: This links gives details on using java-8 https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Comment: It's deprecated and now entirely unnecessary