# Android - I dont manage to activate Jack & Jill

Tags: android, java-8, android-jack-and-jill

In my Android project I need to use a dependency that requires java 8 so i'm trying to use jack

```
{
 ...
 jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

but I get this error

> Error:Could not get unknown property 'classpath' for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForLiteDebug' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.

Comment: Please show the full gradle file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable Jack (Java Android Compiler Kit) in android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36880115/how-to-enable-jack-java-android-compiler-kit-in-android-studio)

Comment: I think it because I use Realm

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Your error is an issue with your Gradle syntax. Please [edit] your question to show the full file as well as the root module  Gradle file